# A problem for LaTeX's \@ifnextchar

Tags: tex-core

I wanted to construct a command, say `\newlet`, that I could use to do

```
\newlet\x\y
```

and/or

```
\newlet\x=\y
```

such that `\x` is unique (ie, not already in use).

Here we go

```
\protected\def\newlet#1{%
  \@ifnextchar={\@firstoftwo{\@newlet{#1}}}{\@newlet{#1}}%
}
\def\@newlet#1{\@ifdefinable{#1}\relax\let#1= }

% Obviously works:
\newlet\sptoken=\@sptoken

% Obviously fails:
\newlet\sptoken\@sptoken
```

Comment: Could I ask what the idea is here? It's quite possible to define a function `\newlet` which will carry out a check and which works with implicit spaces, but the optional `=` is a pain.

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of `\@ifnextchar`. I really wanted to do `\newlet\temp@sptoken\@sptoken` and it failed. I then traced the problem to the fact that `\@xifnch` expects an explicit blank space. In essence can `\@ifnextchar` be modified to work in 'all' cases?

Comment: @AhmedMusa You could use amsmath's `\new@ifnextchar`, but then `\newlet\x= \y` would not work.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I knew about Michael Downes' `\new@ifnextchar` in AMS packages, but as you have noted, `\newlet\x= \y` fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dealing with spaces in a general way is tricky. What you want here is a peek-ahead-and-remove function. This is available in LaTeX3 as `\peek_meaning_remove:NTF`, where I would use

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \newlet #1
  {
    \peek_meaning_remove:NTF =
      { \cs_new_eq:NN #1 }
      { \cs_new_eq:NN #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\newlet\sptoken=\@sptoken
```

This can of course be 'written out' in primitives. Ignoring the need to be careful about `&` tokens (using an Appendix D trick), something like

```
\makeatletter
\protected\long\def\newlet#1{%
  \protected\def\@newlet@fcommon{%
    \ifdefined#1%
      \expandafter\ERROR
    \fi
    \let#1= 
  }%
  \let\@tempa= =%
  \futurelet\@let@token\@newlet
}
\protected\def\@newlet{%
  \ifx\@let@token\@tempa
    \expandafter\@newlet@true
  \else
    \expandafter\@newlet@fcommon
  \fi
}
\protected\def\@newlet@true{%
    \afterassignment\@newlet@fcommon
    \let\@temp@= %
}
```

will work (it's a simplified version of `\peek_meaning_remove:NTF` with the branches hard-coded). Notice in particular that the `=` is removed using a `\let` along with an `\afterassignment` to regain control, rather than using a parameter.

The basic idea here is not dis-similar to `\@ifnextchar`, but does not include the loop to remove spaces which the latter does. The LaTeX3 bundle provides both 'pre-packaged' (the equivalent to `\@ifnextchar` is `\peek_meaning_remove_spaces:NTF).

Comment: Thanks. But this fails for `\def\z#1{\newlet\y#1}\z{ }=\z`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa I'm not sure what you mean. In your example, `\y` is `\let` to a space, and only then to you have an `=`. As that is after `\z`, it ends up being typeset.

Comment: I was referring to the need for space gobbling as LaTeX kernel's \@ifnextchar does. In `\newlet\y<forced space>=\z`, I would expect `<forced space>` to be gobbled first. Thanks. I will try a scheme by Donald Arseneau that I saw applied in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on Joseph Wright's idea:

```
\protected\long\def\newlet#1{%
  \def\@newlet##1{%
    \ifdefined#1%
      \@latex@error{Command '\string#1' already exists}\@ehc
    \fi
    \let#1=
  }%
  \futurelet\@let@token\@@newlet
}
\protected\def\@@newlet{%
  \ifx\@let@token=%
    \expandafter\@newlet
  \else
    \expandafter\@newlet\expandafter\relax
  \fi
}
```

But it still fails for

```
\def\z#1{\newlet\y#1}\z{ }=\z
```